# How can I use a RN lib in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, react-native, portability

I have a React Native library that needs to be used in a flutter project, is there a way for me to use it? (I have 0 skill in flutter)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. What library?

Comment: You can't, how this was supposed to be? How can you install a npm module through Dart dependency manager? How are you supposed to use a different architecture code inside Flutter framework? How about tree shaking from Flutter? Definitely we can do it some way, but it will be a unnecessary overengineering.

Comment: You can do it the other way round, maybe export as a android lib

Comment: I dont think so, React Native uses bridge, Flutter doesn't, there's so many architectural differences I can't think on way to do it at least.